# How can I fix the errors transform not exist?

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine

```
using UnityEngine;
using System.Collections;

public class MakeTwoPoints3D : MonoBehaviour {

    public GameObject cylinderPrefab;

    // Use this for initialization
    void Start () {

        CreateCylinderBetweenPoints(Vector3.zero, new Vector3(10, 10, 10), 0.5f);

    }

    void CreateCylinderBetweenPoints(Vector3 start, Vector3 end, float width)
    {
        var offset = end - start;
        var scale = new Vector3(width, offset.magnitude / 2.0f, width);
        var position = start + (offset / 2.0f);


        Object cylinder = Instantiate(cylinderPrefab, position, Quaternion.identity);
        cylinder.transform.up = offset;
        cylinder.transform.localScale = scale;
    }

    // Update is called once per frame
    void Update () {

    }
}
```

On both lines same error:

```
cylinder.transform.up = offset;
cylinder.transform.localScale = scale;
```

> Severity  Code    Description Project File    Line    Suppression State
>   Error   CS1061  'Object' does not contain a definition for 'transform' and no extension method 'transform' accepting a first argument of type 'Object' could be found (are you missing a using directive or an assembly reference?) MakeTwoPoints3D.cs  23  Active

Comment: Why are you declaring as `Object`?

Comment: After reading [here](https://unity3d.com/learn/tutorials/topics/scripting/instantiate), I see you are instantiating based on the variable `cylinderPrefab`, and cylinderPrefab has type `GameObject`, so change the call to this: `GameObject cylinder = Instantiate(cylinderPrefab, position, Quaternion.identity) as GameObject;`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`Object` is parent class of `GameObject` and `GameObject` as member of type `Transform`. If you try to access `transform` from an instance of `Object` class, it will show you following error:

> Object' does not contain a definition for 'transform'

So accurate way of instantiating and using the resulted object as a GameObject is as Quantic said in [comment](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/40364588/how-can-i-fix-the-erorrs-transform-not-exist#comment67982388_40364588) :

```
GameObject cylinder = Instantiate(cylinderPrefab, position, Quaternion.identity) as GameObject;
```

OR

```
GameObject cylinder = (GameObject) Instantiate(cylinderPrefab, position, Quaternion.identity);
```

It is always to use null-check for safety before using the component in case of other types than GameObject. For example:

```
Rigidbody rb = Instantiate(somePrefab) as Rigidbody;
if(rb != null)
  // use it here
```

hope this helps.